# codeigniter check id available in different table in same

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

working in a project which need to check del id is in `liked`table or not.

```
b.deal_available_city,
            b.shippingType,b.priceType,b.dealId,b.dealUrl,b.dealTitle,b.slug,b.dealDetails,b.extraDetails,b.isHomeScreenBigDeal,b.deal_available_city,
            b.aditionalDetails,b.status,b.dateAdded,b.categoryId,b.siteId,b.isPinned,b.priceId,b.price,b.startDate,b.endDate,b.NumberOfClicked,b.discountPrice,b.discountPercentage,b.dealBrandId,
            b.endTime,b.startTime,b.howtousethisoffer,b.deal_location,b.cancellationpolicy,b.dealType,b.totalavailabledeals,b.numberofdealused,
            b.addedTime,i.thumbImage,i.imageUrl,i.normalimageurl,s.SiteUrl,s.SiteName,s.Site_alias,s.SiteLogo,c.cat_name,c.cat_color,c.cat_alias,p.price_name,
            p.price_symbol,p.price_shortcode,st.shId,st.shipping_text

$this->db->from('dealdetails as b');
        $this->db->join('dealImages i', 'i.dealId = b.dealId','left');
        $this->db->join('brand s', 's.SiteId = b.siteId','left');
        $this->db->join('shipping_details st', 'st.shId = b.shippingType','left');
        $this->db->join('price_type p', 'p.id = b.priceId','left');
        $this->db->join('coupon_category c', 'c.catId = b.categoryId','left');
        //$this->db->join('dealfavorite l', 'l.id = b.dealId','left');
        $this->db->where('b.showinhomescreen','1');
        $this->db->where('i.imgisdefault','1');
        $this->db->where('i.status','1');
        $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$this->input->cookie('city', TRUE).",b.deal_available_city) !=", 0);
        $this->db->where('b.startTime <=',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $this->db->where('b.endTime >= ',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $this->db->group_by('b.dealId');
        $this->db->order_by("b.dealId", "desc");
```

Now situation is like that need to check id is in `liked` table or not. Please check once and suggest me the way how to do it

Comment: add `$this->db->where("b.dealId in (select id from liked where userId =$userId)", null, false)`

Comment: and how to pass user id with this?? example is like loop of multiple deals and also check the deal is liked by logedin user.

Comment: add `$this->db->where("b.dealId in (select l.dealId from liked l where l.userId =$userId)", null, false)`

Comment: it's showing only those data which is liked by user, we need the query if liked return true and if not return false. I am not in fully CI/ Php developer , basically from IOS . There is some error and asking u the lip. Plz

Comment: Ok. Give me a minute.

Comment: `$this->db->join('liked l', "l.dealId = b.dealId AND l.userId = $userId",'left');`


In this case, if you find `l.userId` `null` that means the user has not liked the deal.
Remove that `where` condition I suggested.

Comment: $this->db->join('dealfavorite l', 'l.id = b.dealId AND l.user_id = '.$logedinUser,'left'); and insted of two result showing 1 where table is like this - https://ibb.co/dU8sQQ . Where i am wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149877/discussion-between-jagad89-and-santanu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below statement to get desired output.

`$this->db->join('dealfavorite l', 'l.deal_id = b.dealId AND l.user_id = '.$logedinUser,'left');`

to get the favorite status, you can add `select` as below.

`$this->db->select("*, if(l.user_id>0,'Yes','No') as favorite" , FALSE);`